# Unassigned Attributes from an attribute set Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

How Can I unnasigned an attribute from an attribute set without deleting it, in case I need to assign it back. I use Magento 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Catalog-> Manage Attribute-> Attribute set.
Select Attribute set you want to modify. lets say default. 
Then you will just need to drag and drop that attribute which you want to unassign from set.

Comment: Thank you Mohit, I tried that but I received the following message "You cannot remove system attribute from this set" I am trying to remove the "Size Chart" from Additional Information. Any advise?

Comment: To remove System attribute you will need to set "is_user_defined" field value to 1 in "eav_attribute" table for that attribute in database.